# Assigning numbers manually in ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want to assign 3 numbers manually in a field

[image]

at the field of Ddensity i want to assign 10,40,85 ... how can i do that?

Comment: Do you just want to edit Manually ?  Or are you looking to assign based on another charecteristic ?   Color = 7 then 10, Color = 12 then 40  etc ?

Comment: yes exactly right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the Feature Class "bound" in the table of contents and select edit.
Then you should be able to enter the numbers into each box.